Next-auth configuration redirection issue
I am using next-auth in nextjs for my authentication. After authentication with google provider, I am getting only a refresh and I need to manually enter the address I was navigated from to access it after authentication. What am I doing wrong?
// src\app\api\auth\[...nextauth]\route.ts

...
export const authConfig: NextAuthOptions = {
    providers: [
        GoogleProvider({
            clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID as string,
            clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET as string,
            authorization: {
                params: {
                    redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:3000/api/auth/callback/google'
                }
            }
        }),
        GitHubProvider({
            clientId: process.env.GITHUB_ID as string,
            clientSecret: process.env.GITHUB_SECRET as string,

            profile: (profile) => {
                return {
                    id: profile.id.toString(),
                    name: profile.login ?? profile.name,
                    email: profile.email,
                    image: profile.avatar_url,
                }
            },

        }),
    ],    
    callbacks: {
        session({ session, token }) {
            if (session.user) {
                session.user.id = token.sub || "";
            }
            return session;
        }
    },
    pages: {
        signIn: "/home/auth",
        error: "/home/error",
    },

}

const handler = NextAuth(authConfig)


export { handler as GET, handler as POST }


// src\middleware.ts

import { withAuth } from "next-auth/middleware"

export default withAuth({
    // Matches the pages config in `[...nextauth]`
    pages: {
        signIn: "/home/auth",
        error: "/home/error",
    },
})
export const config = { matcher: ["/home/form/:path*", "/home/dashboard/:path*"] }

The url looks something like this http://localhost:3000/home/auth?callbackUrl=%2Fhome%2Fform. I am assuming after authentication the callback should automatically redirect to /home/form as shown in the web browser url.
Update
The signin function is import from next-auth
'use client'
import { signIn } from "next-auth/react";
...
    const handleClick = (providerName: string) => {
        signIn(providerName);
        
    }
...

                    <button onClick={() => handleClick("google")}>
...
                            <FcGoogle className="absolute left-0 w-5" />
...                        
                    </button>



can you update the question with the signIn function

I believe you have the GoogleProvider wrong. That authorization property is wrongly setted.

What you should do is delete the authorization property and use the callbackUrl on the signIn component
signIn('google', { callbackUrl: 'http://localhost:3000/bar' })

As you can see from the Docs
